# Why shouldn't I put "using namespace std" in a header?

Tags: c++, header-files, using

Someone once hinted that doing this in a header file is not advised:

```
using namespace std;
```

Why is it not advised?

Could it cause linker errors like this: (linewrapped for convenience)

```
error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct 
std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::
~basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > 
(void)" (??1?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@XZ) 
already defined in tools.lib(Exception.obj)
```

Comment: I don't even put in my .cpp files.  I prefer to use `std::vector<std::string>` etc

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because it forces anyone who uses your header file to bring the `std` namespace into global scope.  This could be a problem if they have a class that has the same name as one of the standard library classes.

Answer (score 1):

If the file gets included elsewhere the compilation unit will implicitely get the using directive. This can lead to confusing errors when names overlap.

Comment: could it cause linker errors like this: error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(void)" (??1?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@XZ) already defined in tools.lib(Exception.obj)
??

Comment: @Tony: You should add this to the question. It would be easier to read with proper formatting.